# Populate a column with input based on partial match from another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet 1 where the column contains a list of domains e.g. [www.nonsence.bg/sport](http://www.nonsence.bg/sport), [www.example.cn/streets](http://www.example.cn/streets), [www.news.gr/sports](http://www.news.gr/sports)

I would like to populate the Country input in column A based on the "KEY" table that is stored within the sheet 4 where column A = the domain (e.g. ".gr/", ".bg/", ".cn/") and column B = country (Greece, China, Bulgaria).

I use the following code for find/replace, but with the partial match it seems to be a bit more complex:

```
Sub substitute()

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim FndList, x&


Set Sh1 = Sheets(1)
Set Sh2 = Sheets(3)
FndList = Sh2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
For x = 1 To UBound(FndList)
    Sh1.Cells.Replace What:=FndList(x, 1), replacement:=FndList(x, 2), LookAt:=xlPart
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of your worksheet and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially since your entries in `KEY` table are of the form `xx/`, it's pretty easy to do this with a formula:

*I made the key table into a "real" table and am using structured references, but you can change that to normal references if you prefer*

```
B2: =INDEX(tblKEY[Country], MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & tblKEY[Domain]&"*",A2,0)),0))
```

**KEY table** 
*(named `tblKEY`)*

[image]

**Results**

[image]

You can do the same thing with VBA and the `Range.Find` method, if you must use VBA for some other reason:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Country()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, LO As ListObject
    Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range, CC As Range
    
'Change these to represent your actual locations
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet5")
Set rSrc = wsSrc.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(rowoffset:=1)
Set LO = wsSrc.ListObjects("tblKEY")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rSrc.Columns(2).ClearContents
For Each CC In LO.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
    With rSrc.Columns(1)
        Set C = .Find(what:=CC.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            C.Offset(0, 1) = CC.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    End With
Next CC
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this works fine, but how would I translate it into VBA as my cells can not contain formulas as they could be deleted by the user. Thank you

Comment: Hi Ron, great, thanks so much. Now I am struggling with a very similar issue! trying to populate the columns F of Sheet 1 with the continent of the respective country (which is now populated in column A based on the domain as per above)..this is once again based on the county-continent pairs seen in the list stored in the sheet 4. I have re-named the range but the re-modified code keeps does not seem to recognize the named range unfortunately. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you want correctly, this should work

```
Sub UpdateCountries()
    Dim vCountriesList As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
        vCountriesList = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lLastRow
            For j = 1 To UBound(vCountriesList, 1)
                If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "H"), vCountriesList(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    If .Cells(i, "A").Value <> vCountriesList(j, 2) Then
                        .Cells(i, "A").Value = vCountriesList(j, 2)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing works like a charm! just one more question, what if then wanted to populate the  cell F(sheet1) with the continent of the country based on the criteria table stored in  a similar table as the above, but within Sheet5? i.e. column A of sheet 5 would be the country and column B the continent and based on this, the column F of sheet1 would be populated with the corresponding continent (in respect to column A)? Thanks again

Comment: What you're describing is almost identical to what has already been answered. You should be able to change the codes provided. As @RonRosenfeld said (in his comment), if you cannot make it work, then post another question and people here will try to adjust the code for you.